# how to catch pg_connect() function error?

Tags: php, postgresql

pg_connect() is showing the error in table format.Instead of showing error message as table format need a error message alert.

> Error Message
>     Warning: pg_connect() [function.pg-connect]: Unable to connect to PostgreSQL server: FATAL: password authentication failed for user "test" in /home/test/public_html/QueueManager/Modules/Database.php on line 41

After if showing error as table format.
After executing pg_connect() throwed exception.
But is is not working.

Code

```
function connect()
{
  $HOST = $GLOBALS[Database_Conn][Db_Host];     # Host name 
  $USER = $GLOBALS[Database_Conn][Db_User];     # database user name 
  $DBNAME = $GLOBALS[Database_Conn][Db_Name];   # name of the database
  $PASSWORD = $GLOBALS[Database_Conn][Db_Pass]; # password the database user.

  try 
  {
    $conn = pg_connect("host=$HOST dbname=$DBNAME user=$USER ".
                       "password=$PASSWORD sslmode=disable");
    if(!$conn)
    {
      throw new Exception("Database Connection Error");
    }
    return $conn;
  }
  catch (Exception $e) 
  {
    print <<<_HTML_
    <script> alert('Caught exception'); 
    </script> _HTML_;
    die();
  }
}
```

Please give me the solution

Comment: Isn't it kind of wired that you throw an exception while catching an exception...? (honest question, does PHP support this kind of throwing exceptions)

Comment: Yes, PHP 5 and up supports exceptions. I guess his code is like that because he's testing the exception stuff. The problem is that the "Warning: pg_connect()" message is generated *before* pg_connect even returns.

Comment: @DrColossos :: Probably he wants to hide the default exception which is revealing the username used in the connection attempt, in this case that message being: `password authentication failed for user "test" `

Answer (score 22):

`pg_connect` does not throw exception, so you have to translate to exception like below.

```
function exception_error_handler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline ) {
    throw new ErrorException($errstr, $errno, 0, $errfile, $errline);
}
set_error_handler("exception_error_handler");

try {
    $conn=@pg_connect("host=dbhost user=dbuser dbname=db password=dbpass");
} Catch (Exception $e) {
    Echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Please refer this more detail

http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Answer (score 6):

To hide the error text generated by PHP, add @ in front of the function call, e.g.:

```
$conn = @pg_connect("host=$HOST dbname=$DBNAME user=$USER ".
                   "password=$PASSWORD sslmode=disable");
```

More [details here](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.errorcontrol.php)

Comment: Keep in mind that if the `pg_connect()` function doesn't exist, your script will still die, but you will see no error.