# How do I start a PGSQL connection in PHP?

Tags: php, postgresql

I am trying to start a pgsql connection in php but i get **pg_last_error(): No PostgreSQL link opened yet** Please forgive my amateur question as i am a bit new to php.

Here is my php code:

```
<?php

$connect = pg_connect("host=xxx.xx.xxx.21 dbname=d106 user=b16 password=bran") or die("Could not connect: " . pg_last_error());

$result = pg_query($connect,"SELECT distinct thestartgeom FROM bikes");
if (!$result)
{
echo "no results ";
}

while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{

 $coor = $row['thestartgeom'];
echo $coor;

}

pg_close($connect);
?>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your pgsql connection you have missed the port number.
Try this way.

```
<?php
$host        = "host=xxx.xx.xxx.21";
$port        = "port=5432";
$dbname      = "dbname=d106";
$credentials = "user=b16 password=bran";

$connect= pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  ) or die("Could not connect: " . pg_last_error());


$result = pg_query($connect,"SELECT distinct thestartgeom FROM bikes");
if (!$result)
{
echo "no results ";
}

while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{

 $coor = $row['thestartgeom'];
echo $coor;

}

pg_close($connect);
?>
```

**You can store PgSQL connection code in one PHP file to reuse**

**pgsql_db_connection.php** file

```
<?php
$host        = "host=xxx.xx.xxx.21";
$port        = "port=5432";
$dbname      = "dbname=d106";
$credentials = "user=b16 password=bran";

$connect= pg_connect( "$host $port $dbname $credentials"  );
if(!$connect){
  echo "Error : Unable to open database\n";
}
?>
```

Call `pgsql_db_connection.php` file in other php files to use your database connection.

```
<?php
require_once('pgsql_db_connection.php');

 $result = pg_query($connect,"SELECT distinct thestartgeom FROM bikes");
if (!$result)
{
echo pg_last_error($connect);
  exit;
}

while($row = pg_fetch_array($result))
{

$coor = $row[0];
echo $coor;

}
?>
```

Comment: hey man, thanks for your response. I receive **E_WARNING : type 2 -- pg_last_error(): No PostgreSQL link opened yet**

Comment: Also, i am not trying to connect via local host, i am trying to connect to a remote pgsql db.

Comment: have you allowed remote connections to the database server by configuring the pg_hba.conf file?

Comment: Are you using heroku?

Answer (score 2):

When `pg_connect` fails, it returns FALSE and produces a PHP warning with the detailed information on why it couldn't initiate the connection. If you can see the other message:`pg_last_error(): No PostgreSQL link opened yet` that you're reporting, I'd expect you should be able to see the previous one too, which is the one normally telling the reason of the failure.

If the `display_errors` configuration setting is set to `0`, the first message would not show up on the browser/screen but the second would not either.

Anyway, assuming you can't have access to `pg_connect` warnings for whatever reason such as custom error handler, what's wrong with your code is that `pg_last_error()` must have an already opened connection to work.

To access the detailed error message from a failed `pg_connect`, the built-in PHP function `error_get_last()` (returning an  array) could be used.

```
<?
$connect= pg_connect("your-connect-string");
if (!$connect) {
  print_r(error_get_last());
  // for only the message:
  // echo error_get_last()['message']
}
die("DB connection failed");
?>
```

See also [how to catch pg_connect() function error?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4253136/how-to-catch-pg-connect-function-error) if you prefer exceptions.